# How do I know if I'm using a GPU?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, system, system-settings, gpu

How to find out in Ubuntu (14.04) whether the processor has a GPU or not? I went through a few links and the results are as given below for my system specs.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               1067.484
BogoMIPS:              7183.17
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

This the what is shown in the details section.

[image]

So given the above details, does the system contain a GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graphics processing unit (**GPU**), also occasionally called visual processing unit (**VPU**), You can also use to see its output:

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12

Or 

lshw -numeric -C display or video
```

or

```
lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
```

Output:

```
05:07.0 VGA compatible controller: XGI Technology Inc. (eXtreme Graphics    Innovation) Z7/Z9 (XG20 core)
```

Comment: Yes, I have executed the commands and all of the outputs have `Xeon E3-1200` in common. So, coming back to the question, can I conclude that I have a GPU in my system?

Comment: Yes Its GPU information ..you are looking!.